# Material-Ui reordered css upon react build when deploying to heroku

Tags: reactjs, build, material-ui

my build is not working correctly in build when i deploy to heroku. i have read about reordering the css but how do i verify this or make it work with material ui.

i have tried to look at the inspector and verify css is reordered.

this is the container and the whole screen and is being set off a good bit. the whole build in total has extra padding and the header is not working correctly. it can hopefully be seen at this address.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import { logoutUser } from '../../actions/authActions';
import { getSongs, getSong } from '../../actions/songActions';
import { clearCurrentProfile, getCurrentProfile } from '../../actions/profileActions';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import FadeIn from 'react-fade-in';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';

import Editor from "./Editor";
import Viewer from "./Viewer";
import ANContainer from '../audio-and-notes/ANContainer';
import AddSongModal from './AddSongModal';
import Resources from '../resources/Resources';
import Songs from '../songs/Songs';
import Song from '../song/Song';
import Spinner from '../../common/Spinner';
import { MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";
import { ExpansionPanelDetails } from "@material-ui/core";

const logo = require('../../img/songbird-logo.png');

const drawerWidth = 276;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 24, // keep right padding when drawer closed
  },
  toolbarIcon: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  appBar: {
    backgroundColor: "#203e55",
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  menuButtonHidden: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  //right side menu
  menu2Button: {
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
  },
  menu2ButtonHidden: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  //songbook
  drawerTitle: {
    color: "white",
    flexGrow: 1,
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  //songbird 
  title: {
      marginLeft: "300px",
      flexGrow: 1,
      fontFamily: 'Open Sans, sans-serif'
  },

  drawerPaper: {
    backgroundColor: "#203e55",
    color: "white",
    position: 'relative',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerPaperClose: {
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),

    //how much it pops out from the drawer pre-view
    width: theme.spacing.unit * 0,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing.unit * 0,
    },
  },
  appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    height: '96.6vh',
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
  h5: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
});

const options = ["Viewer", "Resources", "Notes"];


class AppContainer extends Component {

  state = {
    open: false,
    left: false,
    right: false,
    anchorEl: null,
    selectedIndex: 0
  };

    toggleDrawer = (side, open) => () => {
      this.setState({ [side]: open 
      });
    };


    componentDidMount(){
      this.props.getSongs();
      this.props.getCurrentProfile();
    }


 //trying to maintain the component state for switcher


    pageControl() {
      if (this.state.selectedIndex === 0) {
        return <Viewer />;
      } else if (this.state.selectedIndex === 1) {
        return <Resources />;
      } else if (this.state.selectedIndex === 2) {
        return <ANContainer />;
      }
    }

    toggleDrawer = (side, open) => () => {
    this.setState({
      [side]: open,
    });
    };

    handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    handleDrawerClose = () => {
      this.setState({ open: false });       
      };

    handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });    
    };    

    handleDrawerClose = () => { 
    this.setState({ open: false });  
    };    


     handleClickListItem = event => {
      this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
      this.pageControl();
     };

    handleMenuItemClick = (event, index) => {
      this.setState({ selectedIndex: index, anchorEl: null });
    };
    handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
    };


    openSongModal = () => {
    //open popup here
    }

    onLogoutClick(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.clearCurrentProfile();
      this.props.logoutUser();
    }

    render(){
        //for routing
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;
        const { profile, loading } = this.props.profile;
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { anchorEl } = this.state;

        //will display iframe for wix site if the user does not have an account 
        const unauthContent = (
          <div>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <Link to="/" class="brand-logo"><img className="navlogo" src={logo} /></Link>

            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><Link to="/register">Sign Up</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/login">Log In</Link></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <iframe 
          style={{height: "92vh", width: "100%"}} 
          src="https://www.songbirdapp.com/" 
          frameBorder="none"> 
        </iframe>
      </div>
        );

        //rendered content
        return(

          <div className={classes.root}>
          <CssBaseline />

          {/* NAVBAR SECTION!!! */}
          <AppBar
            position="absolute"
            className={classNames(classes.appBar, this.state.open && classes.appBarShift)}
          >
           <Toolbar disableGutters={!this.state.open} className={classes.toolbar}>
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="Open drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                className={classNames(
                  classes.menuButton,
                  this.state.open && classes.menuButtonHidden,
                )}
              >
               <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography
                component="h1"
                variant="h6"
                color="inherit"
                noWrap
                className={classes.title}
              >
                Editor
              </Typography>

              <div className="hide-on-med-and-down">


              </div>

              {/* TO CHANGE THE VIEWER RESOURCE PANEL */}
              <List
              component="nav-wrapper"
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignContent: "center",
                justifyContent: "flex-end",
                width: "14%",
                backgroundColor: "transparent"
              }}
            >
              <ListItem
                button
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-controls="lock-menu"
                aria-label="Select Resource"
                onClick={this.handleClickListItem}
              >
                <ListItemText
                  style={{
                    color: "white"
                  }}
                  primary={options[this.state.selectedIndex]}
                />
                <ExpandMoreIcon />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
            <Menu
              id="lock-menu"
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
              onClose={this.handleClose}
            >
              {options.map((option, index) => (
                <MenuItem
                  key={option}
                  disabled={index === 4}
                  selected={index === this.state.selectedIndex}
                  onClick={event =>
                    this.handleMenuItemClick(event, index) & this.pageControl()
                  }
                >
                  {option}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>

            {/* End Resources */}
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
           {/* NAVBAR SECTION END */}


              {/* LEFT DRAWER  */}
          <Drawer
            variant="permanent"
            classes={{
              paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, !this.state.open && classes.drawerPaperClose),
            }}
            open={this.state.open}
          >
            <div className={classes.toolbarIcon}>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.drawerTitle}>
              Songs
            </Typography>
              <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
                <ChevronLeftIcon style={{color: "white"}}/>
              </IconButton>
            </div>
            <Divider />

            <List>
                <AddSongModal />

                <Songs />
            </List>

            <Divider />

            <List>
            <ListItem>
            <Link className="menu-listitem" to="/myprofile">
              {user.firstName} {user.lastName} 
              </Link>
              </ListItem>

                <ListItem>
                  <Link className="menu-listitem" to="/subscription">
                    Your Subscription
                    </Link>
                </ListItem> 
                <ListItem>
                  <a className="logout-listitem"
                    href="" 
                    onClick={this.onLogoutClick.bind(this)}
                    >
                    Logout</a>
                </ListItem> 
            </List>

          </Drawer>

             {/* LEFT DRAWER END */}


 <main className={classes.content}>
          <div
            className="row no-padding"
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              margin: 0
            }}
          >
            <div
              className="col s12 no-padding"
              style={{
                margin: 0
              }}
            >
              <Song />
            </div>


            <div className="col s12 m9 no-padding" style={{}}>
              {this.pageControl()}
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>

               {/* RIGHT DRAWER TO BE USED FOR DRAFTS */}


            {/* <Drawer
            anchor="right"
            variant="permanent"
            classes={{
              paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, !this.state.open && classes.drawerPaperClose),
            }}
            open={this.state.open}
          >
            <div className={classes.toolbarIcon}>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.drawerTitle}>
              Songs
            </Typography>
              <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerTwoClose}>

                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          <List>
          <ListItem>Draft 04/12/2019 1PM</ListItem>
          <ListItem>Draft 04/12/2019 12:30PM</ListItem>
          <ListItem>Draft 04/10/2019 3PM</ListItem>
          <ListItem>Draft 04/09/2019 11AM</ListItem>
          <ListItem>Draft 04/09/2019 9PM</ListItem>
          <ListItem>Draft 04/08/2019 8:34PM</ListItem>

            </List>
          </Drawer> */}

              {/* RIGHT DRAWER END  */}   
            </div>


        );   
    }
}

AppContainer.propTypes = {
    getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    song: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired, 

    getSongs: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    profile: state.profile,
    auth: state.auth,
    song: state.song,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logoutUser, getCurrentProfile, clearCurrentProfile, getSongs, getSong })(withStyles(styles)(AppContainer));
```

https://ovrchr-songbirdapp.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Hi Scott, welcome to SO! Could you give us more details? What part of the CSS you are having problems with? Are you overwriting it with some custom styles or using some library like `StyledComponents`? Maybe paste some code to help us visualize what you mean by "reorder the CSS".

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro I updated the main post with my app container. the components use material-ui as well. maybe this will point to some problems. it is basically messing up the formatting alot when i do the deployment build in heroku.

Comment: Hi @ScottMercer. Do you have an actual question? I am not sure how we can help you.

Comment: Yeah how do you fix the css from on a build. i cannot predict what the mix up is going to be on deployment and pre code it into the app.